# Position image on page with title using ImageMagick or similar command line tool

Tags: image, command-line, imagemagick

I have a landscape image `foo.png` which I'd like to lay out on a page like this:

```
+--------------+
|              |
|  title text  |
|              |
|  +--------+  |
|  |foo.png |  |
|  |        |  |
|  +--------+  |
|              |
|              |
+--------------+
```

I've got the image positioned properly on the page with:

`convert -background white -page letter+20+300 -resize 572x572 foo.png -layers flatten laid-out.png`

However, I can't find the right use of `-annotate`, `-draw text` or `label:` to get that `title text` to show up in the right place.

The eventual goal is to script this for about a hundred images, so I need a command-line solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'd do well to take advantage of ImageMagick's "-gravity" setting here. This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but notice how "-gravity" works to locate the overlay image with "-composite", and the text is located with "-annotate" using a command like this...

```
convert foo.png -resize 572x572 \
   -size 612x792 xc:white +swap -gravity center -composite \
   -gravity north -pointsize 24 -annotate +0+100 "Title Text" laid-out.png
```

That starts by reading in "foo.png" and resizing it. Then it sets the size of the desired canvas, creates a white canvas of that size, sets the gravity to center, swaps the overlay image with the canvas to get them in the correct order, and composites "foo.png" centered on the canvas.

Then it changes the gravity setting to north, sets the pointsize of the text, and annotates the image with the text located "+0+100". That's zero pixels from center left to right, and 100 pixels down from the top.

A couple experiments should help you find settings to suit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to do it in ImageMagick using montage.

logo.jpg

[image]

```
montage -title "Testing" logo.jpg -geometry 160x120+25+25 -tile 1x1 -frame 0 -background white logo_title.jpg
```

[image]

The geometry argument 160x120 resizes to that dimension and the +25+25 adds a border of that size. Note that this gives somewhat less flexibility in positioning the title than GeeMack's solution.